# SQL Server is not a valid installation folder how to fix location

Tags: sql-server, installation, center

I want to install SQL server on my pc, but when I am try to give path for installation, I am getting this error, the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\ is not valid installation folder, I tried other drives but still no result.

Here is the image of SQL Server installation center with the error path
SQL Server installation center with the error path

[image]

Comment: why you are chaing the current installation path ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please see if what sql server version\edition (64 or 32bit) you try to install 
what is your OS?

and if you have the right .exe, right click  and "run as admin" i hope this one will help you. :)

Answer (score 43):

Open **SQL SERVER Installation Centre**, go to:

*Option* **->** *Select installation media root directory* **->** *browse to the folder* which has .msi file of SQL (Should be something like `C:\SQLServer2016Media\ExpressAdv_ENU\`)

Comment: This solved my problem. For me accepted folder path was "C:\SQL2019\Evaluation_ENU" for MS SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 11):

When you click on the exe installer it will show you a folder that the installer will extract too.  For instance mine was **C:\SQL2019** (see image bellow).

[image]

In order to launch the command center with the correct installion folder just browse the installation folder until you find the Setup.exe file and point the installation folder to it.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU should work for 2019 version

Answer (score 3):

I received an installation of SQL Server 2012 from a corporate self-service push.  Ran setup.exe as Administrator and set the installation media folder.  Error message persisted.

Downloaded media directly from MS and compared the setup folders.

In my case, the corporate push excluded the MEDIAINFO.xml file in the setup directory.  Copying the file (from MS install) to my setup folder enabled its use as the installation media folder.[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi3nU.png)

Comment: Where was this file originally located (when you say MS install)?

Comment: After downloading the SQL Server media from microsoft, you will find MediaInfo.xml in the root once mounted or extracted..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you just have the SQL Installation Center because you install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you cannot install the SQL Server. You need to have the SQL Server image file, the .iso file for instance.

Open the .iso file or extract it, launch the SQL Installation Center by clicking the Setup.exe from the folder in the .iso (or in the folder you extracted from the .iso). Then it shall be running fine.

Please visit https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33153123-493e-4bfa-89a3-180c481b5fe4/lt-gt-sql-server-is-not-a-valid-installation-folder?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 2):

Below method works fine for me.
I've looked out several thread and answers but none of them worked for me so I created the solution myself :D

Only for the .exe file ex: SQLExpress16-KBXXXX_X64.exe size approx ~1GB.

- If you have this file then run it as admin.
- It'll extract in `C:\` some place like `C:\cdf6776edfdsfsdf7678`
- Post extraction the setup will autorun. I hope here you are getting the error while setup asks for installation directory.

Do as below:

Once you see setup extract file in place like `C:\cdf6776edfdsfsdf7678`:

- Wait for extract to complete.
- Immediately it autorun setup. PLEASE SELECT "NO". It will give a popup says. 'Setup Canceled by User'. **Don't close the popup**
- Go to the place: `C:\cdf6776edfdsfsdf7678` and copy the whole folder to somewhere else like in `C:\setup`.

You are doing this because If you close the popup that says 'Setup canceled by user' it will delete the extracted file automatically which are contains original installation files.

- Hence before it was deleted we are copying the installation media.

Now Run the `setup.exe` from the files you copied or run the `setup.exe` from start menu and provide the same path once it asks for installation media.

Answer (score 2):

**Context:** You update SQL Server 2019 edition from Express to Developer. The problem is that "SQL SERVER Installation Center" -> Option -> "Select installation media root directory" was not updated and now it appears no folder at all.

**Solution:** Instead of run "SQL SERVER Installation Center"

1. Run the exe-installer that you downloaded when you installed for the very first time.
2. Then select "Custom" installation type, and then it will appear your "Media location" path (e.g.: "C:\SQL2019"). Inside that path, is the valid instance folder (e.g. "C:\SQL2019\ExpressAdv_ENU").
3. Close your exe-installer, and
4. Finally try in "SQL SERVER Installation Center" again.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!  New information comes to light!  Initially, my .exe file was located here:

```
C:\
```

I just moved my .exe file to a new location, which is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me,
Start the installation from the SETUP.EXE file of the SQL server installation directory, which you needed.
https://readdy.net/Notes/Details/596?v=d

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error too. The problem stemmed from using SQL Server Update Package instead of SQL Server Main Installer package. When I used main installer instead of update installer after I've noticed that, the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

For MY Problem i Resolve by select C Drive SQL 2022 folder with Developer edition folder like this => **C:\SQL2022\Developer_ENU**

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

your  SQL server  Installation center use this path that i show in my image it's not work 
it's because your not using SQL Server setup Please Use setup to intall [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv2rh.jpg)